# Can't mount nfs persistent volume in kubernetes, because there is no nfs client install on each slave node

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

After I manually install nfs client package under each node, then it works.
But in GKE, slave node can be scale in and out. After create a new slave node, I lose nfs client package again.

Is there any way we can install software package when kubernetes spin up a new slave node?

Comment: It's running on Google Container Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Starting last week, new GKE clusters should be on created on 1.1.1 by default, and the `nfs-common` package is installed on all 1.1.1 clusters. (For existing clusters, you'll need to wait until the hosted master is upgraded, then initiate a node upgrade.)

See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/examples/nfs/README.md for a larger example.

Answer (score 1):

Please also see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16741 where we're discussing nfs and pretty much exactly this problem (amongst others)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way to automatically run a command when a new GKE node is provisioned.